# is an order isomorphism between X and Y also an order embedding from X into Y?

Tags: order-theory

is an order isomorphism between X and Y also an order embedding from X into Y?

Please assume that X and Y are both well-ordered sets.

I think the answer is yes.. but am not 100% sure. 
Thanks in advance for any tips or guidance you can provide.

Comment: good point.  X and Y are defined as above.  Is the answer still no ?   -  And if no, it would be great if you could add a bit about what makes it not true.  thanks

Comment: Yes, by definition? One also doesn't need $X$ or $Y$ to be well-ordered...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, an embedding is an injective homomorphism, so any isomorphism would qualify.